# Cómo saber dentro del WHERE cual es el ultimo registro de una consulta

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

Necesito aplicar una función al ultimo registro de una consulta en Postgres, también necesito obtener todos los registros y dentro del WHERE preguntar cual es el ultimo, para así aplicar una función.

Sé que puedo hallar el ultimo así: `ORDER BY <campo> DESC LIMIT 1` Pero esto me obligaría a realizar dos consultas porque necesito todos los registros.

Comment: Lo primero de todo, te ayudaría el saber con precisión qué significa cuál es el último. ¿El último ordenado por algo, imagino?

Comment: Por qué haces una pregunta y desapareces? Merece la pena?

Comment: Estaba ocupado haciendo otras cosas y no pude probar, pero ahora que lo probé era lo que buscaba, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No obstante, con la poca información provista, creo que este ejemplo resuelve el problema que planteas:

```
with your_data as (
  select 1 as campo, 'a' as desc union all
  select 2 as campo, 'b' as desc  union all
  select 3 as campo, 'c' as desc
)
select
  d.*,
  case when c.campo is not null then 1 else 0 end as IsTheLast
from your_data d
  left join (
    select max(campo) as campo 
    from your_data
  ) c
  on d.campo=c.campo
```